# To do certain action after deployment

Tags: capistrano, capifony

I am using capifony (it is capistrano for symfony) to deply.

I have to do some work after deployment such as changing access rights for some directories.

```
chmod 0777 test
```

For now I am doing this by manual operation.

Could I include this in my capifony deploy.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about capifony but if you put something like `after 'deploy', 'sometask'` in your capistrano `deploy.rb` file it is ran after deploy.

Here is the list of all the [Capistrano deployment tasks](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks). You can do a `before` or `after` for any of them.

Looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718259/capifony-and-directory-owners) might help you.